# Hostname forward to port

Tags: centos, iptables

I would like to know how to do the following.

I would like so, when you connect to a domain example.com - it'll forward that to lets say 15.46.43.33:26046  (This is for a game, not Apache). Is this possible with IPTables, or any other software for Linux (CentOS 6.2)? - Appreciate it :)

Comment: Please define "connect"

Comment: Like, connect to server - for this example, the game. So they would connect to the server, so they can play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a domain (*example.com* in your example) and a DNS *A record* to associate the hostname to its IP address. If you're on a home DSL connection you may want to check a dynamic DNS service (Google for it) which will update the hostname/IP address association when it changes.

Not really sure this fits ServerFault, though.

Comment: I already have the domain, and it's a dedicated server hosted in a datacenter - all ports are open, so that's not the issues. The domain is already ported to the IP. All I need is the IPTables "command" or what ever it's called - for it to work.

Comment: So start your game server (check with `sudo netstat -putan` its port is open) and connect to it ("example.com:26046" as you say). I don't see any need to forward.

Comment: I can connect perfectly to my server, the issue is that my users need to type the port, and that can get annoying after some time.

Comment: So the client tries to connect to a default port which is different than the one used by your server? And you cannot run the game server at the default port?

Comment: I have many servers I host, and they all can't be on default port. And the issue is that you need to type the port, I would like so you type a hostname such as server1.example.com & then it would connect to: 13.414.5.3:13634.

Comment: No, what you're asking for is not possible unless it is supported by the protocol (as in http, for example). I don't think the game protocol supports this kind of features. It would have been nice to have all these details at the beginning, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible with `iptables` or any higher level `iptables` configuration software, say, `shorewall`. Of course you should point that domain to the Linux router you can control (e.g. login as `root`).

Comment: Already done :) Can you show an example? Thanks :)

Comment: Hmm, it looks like your software resides on the same server your domain points to (from your comment above), is that true? There are two different iptables commands for forwarding the port to the same server and to the other server.

Comment: The domain is pointing at the server, that the game-server is hosted on, and IPTables is on that as well. So, yes that's true.

Comment: Why don't you just listen on that port without a redirection then? Anyway `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport $srcPortNumber -j REDIRECT --to-port $dstPortNumber` should help. Please substitute `eth0`, `$srcPortNumber` and `$dstPortNumber` with real values.

Comment: Almost it! It just need to be a domain name, instead of a port, so I would connect to something.com & it'll redirect that to 10.256.24.21:25754 (example).

Comment: Hmm port redirection is domain agnostic, it will forward all incoming traffic to another port. This is by design, redirection works on network layer 3 and domains are network layer 7 thing. So you are probably doing something wrong, why do you need to explicitly provide a domain name to redirection rule?

Comment: Because the default port is in use, so only one server will be able to do the code you said before.

Comment: Well so you need a layer 7 (protocol aware) proxy then. If the protocol is HTTP you can use `nginx` for proxying different domains to different ports.

Comment: The protocol is TCP, do you have any suggestions for applications, or similar?